# Allow specific HTML tag in htmlentities

Tags: laravel

I used this code to clean data from HTML tags:

```
{!! nl2br(e($a->comment)) !!}
```

But I want allow a specific tag like `iframe`. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you please explain it little more or please share the efforts if you have already tried?

Comment: @RamChander I want clear any html tags except <iframe> when I try show data in blade